# swap values in sed when they match a regex

Tags: sed

I am trying to write a script to take all the php.js functions and create a node.js library for them, Which means I have to figure out how to convert

this

```
function key (arr) {
```

to

```
key: function (arr) {
```

I know sed can do it, But I can't figure it out

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed  's/function\s\(.*\)(/\1: function(/g' file.js
```

That should do the trick

Comment: This gives a space between `key` and `:` correct output is `key:`

Comment: It does: `echo "function key (arr) {" | sed  's/function\s\(.*\)(/\1: function(/g'` gives -> `key : function(arr) {`

Comment: This happens because you have a space between key and the left paren of the arguments list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` to swap fields

```
awk '/function/ {t=$2":";$2=$1;$1=t} 1' file.js
key: function (arr) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed "s/^ *function \{1,\}\([^ ]\{1,\}\) \{1,\}(/\1: function (/" file.js
```

replace the \s by " " assuming there is not tab in white space of the code